# Optimal way to SET/DECLARE a list in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SQL Query based of user input, as these inputs will change on a daily basis.

The goal of the query is to pull all data for only the ID's in the user-defined list. Example below-

However, I am getting the following error:

> "Conversion failed when converting the varchar [...] to data type int"

Any idea on what the optimal way to specify a list and use that list at the "ID in (..)" clause?
I have tried converting the ID list into strings, but still receiving a similar error.

```
id_list = [12,16,22,42,1,24] 
date = '2020-12-18'

query = (
   """
   DECLARE @id varchar(1000), @date datetime
   
   SET @id = '{}'
   SET @date = '{}'

   SELECT * from TABLE where ID in (@id) and Date = @Date
   """
   .format(id_list,date))
```

The desired result is for a query to be able to take a list of IDs that could be utilized in the clause.

> id in @id

Comment: Did you mean `.format(id_list, date)`? Did you print the SQL query and check it against the documentation for syntax-correctness? Abstract away the Python here to streamline your question.

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag because the syntax looks like SQL Server.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, thanks for that - done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't support lists or arrays.  So the best method is a table:

```
declare @id_list table (id int);

insert into @idlist (id)
    values (12), (16), (22), (42), (1), (24);
```

You can then use this wherever you would use a table variable.  For instance:

```
where id in (select id from @id_list)
```

Comment: is there a simpler way to insert vals into this table, maybe via a loop? @gordon

Comment: If you have the values in a table, you can just insert them.  If you want to imagine this as a loop, you can think of "value" as "where".  Or put them in a string and split the string.

Comment: that works just fine. THanks for the info @Gordon. Happy holidays